# Custom, per-file Headers with Static Content in Apache

Tags: apache, http-headers

Is it possible to set up Apache to serve additional headers on a per-file basis without going through something like php or python? Essentially, for all of the files that I have I also have a headers file that I would like to serve it with. For example,

'library.js' has a bunch of javascript and I'd like to serve it with the headers in 'library.js.headers' which might have something like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

but another file, say 'library2.js' has other javascript and I want is served with different headers contained in 'library2.js.headers'.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232739/non-dynamic-custom-http-headers. Answer: `mod_cern_meta`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your separate `.header` file requirement and use the [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files) directive along with [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) to set individual headers per file?

```
<Files library.js>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Files>
```