# Open file linked to href in windows application using Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, html, web-applications, href

I created HTML5 web page that has an href link, this is linked to a file in the SQL server. I need a solution to open the linked file in a windows application like Image viewer, MS Word etc..or pop up an  "Open with" window to choose the application I want to open the file. I want to implement this functionality in Javascript.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried using window.open it opens a new tab to view the image file. But couldn't find any solutions to open using a windows application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387836/open-a-file-with-its-default-programme I think this is what you're trying to do. It appears javascript cannot do this.

Comment: The "open with" option is OS shell extension and is not controlled by the web page. The reason this is not available is because your end system may or may not have the right application and/or the user in the end-system may or may not have rights to open all applications. It is also a security issue that does not allow you to make a shell or system call from web page. But You could write a flash app layer that requests for explicit permissions to open a system app.

Comment: I suppose you could obtain the html from an ajax call to the link in javascript, then somehow manipulate the output as necessary and attempt to auto download this as a docx file?.. It may not work across all browsers.