# Application URI Scheme opening file in program

Tags: html, uri, vlc

I'm trying to get a video to play in VLC via URI

My HTML:

```
<a href="vlc-proto://D:\vids\Desktop\lolaom.mp4">Click Me</a>
```

My Registry:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\vlc-proto" /ve /d "URL:VLC Protocol" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\vlc-proto" /v "URL Protocol" /t REG_SZ /d ""
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\vlc-proto\DefaultIcon" /ve /d "%output%,1" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\vlc-proto\Shell\open\command" /ve /d "\"%output%\" \"%%1\"" /f
```

[image]

It works until the point of VLC trying to open the file I specified above...

[image]

EDIT:
If I remove the first 2 forward slashes in the href link, something interesting happens, for some reason the dir of chrome joins the url and the "vlc-proto" is gone, so maybe there is something similar to the "//" that could also hide the "vlc-proto" and thus finally make it work.
[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with the registry entries, but what happens if you leave out the vlc-proto:// - it looks like it's trying to open the complete URL - instead I guess you simply want the path starting at D:\ - also try verbose mode (-vvv ) in order to get more info on the error.

Comment: Hi Mike, the reg entries creates the custom application protocol to make this possible.
Leaving out "vlc-proto://" makes the link on the page do nothing, "vlc-proto://" is needed though as this tells your computer to do the registry command (open vlc).
Yeah I think it is trying to open the full url too which is very frustrating.
Nothing comes up in verbosity messages at any level.
I just added another picture to my initial post, removing the "//" in the href changes things, what do you think?

Comment: According to https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/ the command should have a space such as "vlc.exe file.mp4". Have you tried simply specifying href="vlc-proto D:\vids\Desktop\lolaom.mp4" I'm not sure. Another approach would be to edit your registry in a way that mp4 files are always opened with VLC. Depending on your use case this may be easier...

Comment: A space makes the browser think it is a link and so tells me the link doesn't exist or other variants brings back the chrome dir with the file (mentioned above).
I'm not sure what you mean about the last point, vlc is already associated in my windows with all video files, I dont think thats an issue either way.

Comment: This sounds similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1387836/693052 however though seems to have no standard solution :-/ maybe look through there? Also, maybe the VLC web plugin would be an option for you: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/

Comment: yeah the problem is chrome removed all plugin support